# nodejs sequelize/cli how to use with node-config

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli, node-config

First off it's my first time with Sequelize so be patient.

I'd like  to use https://github.com/sequelize/cli
along with https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config

I want sequelize to be able to "compose" it's configuration from multiple source files, the same manner that node-config does.

By now I've worked it out with

### .sequelizerc

```
var path = require('path')
var Config = require('config');
var env =Config.util.getEnv('NODE_ENV');
module.exports = {
  'config':          path.resolve('config', env + '.json')
}
```

### development.json ie

```
{
    "app": {
        "name": "my api"
    },
    "server": {
        "port": 8081
    },
    "development": {
            "username": "username",
            "password": "password",
            "database": "database",
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "dialect": "mysql"
    }
}
```

You can see i have to set a redundant env key
with no logical meaning
in all my env.json files.

is there a better way ?

### drawback

To get the data:

```
var env =Config.util.getEnv('NODE_ENV');
var configDb = Config.get(env);
```

and this way all the options of 
File Load Order are lost.

https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Configuration-Files

### Other way

```
sequelize db:migrate --url 'mysql://root:password@mysql_host.com/database_name'
```

with the standard node-config json files.

Comment: Do you think that question is readable? That it makes sense?

Comment: @Amit I've updated my question.

Comment: so you want sequelize to be able to "compose" it's configuration from multiple source files, the same manner that node-config does?

Comment: @Amit could I found better words :) I've edited my question. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In your `config` folder for node-config, create a file called `config.js`

```
// config/config.js
const config = require('config');

module.exports = {
  [process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development']: config.database
};
```

Then create a `.sequelizerc` in the top level of the project.

```
// .sequelizerc
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
 config: path.resolve('config', 'config.js')
};
```

Example `config/development.json`

```
{
  "database": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "",
    "database": "my_database",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
}
```

To use an env var, use `custom-environment-variables.json` as you would normally with node-config.

Comment: I'm using custom-environment-variables.json files, but the properties defined there is not visible in config.js.. Can you please help me find out what is going on

Comment: @Liana can you show me what the project structure looks like? The directory structure you should have is like 

`./config/`

`./config/custom-environment-variables.json`

 `./config/config.js` (sequelize magic, use the code in my answer) 

`./.sequelizerc` (don't forget the ., use the code I put in my answer)

Comment: I solved the problem by adding dotenv on the beginning of my config.js file
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you have to put `.sequelizerc` file at the root of your project with this content:

```
var config = require('config');

config.database.config = __filename;

module.exports = config.database;
```

This exports `database` section of your config, composed from config files by `node-config` as the sequelize-cli config.

Answer (score 1):

There are mistakes in config.js in answer by @type.

1. Must use getter instead of .database
2. `node-config` doesn't allow mutation of config (sequelize try to do)
   Solution is either using `ALLOW_CONFIG_MUTATIONS=true` or spread object.

```js
// config/config.js
const config = require('config');

module.exports = {
  [process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development']: {...config.get('database')},
};
```